# How to use flatten loop for reading multiple VM regions?

Tags: terraform-provider-azure, flatten

I have been facing problem with reading Vm attributes using flatten loop using below format,

```
  advmAccess = {
for k, v in flatten([
   for reg_key, reg in module.regions : [
     for lz_key, lz in local.landingZone : [
       for net_key, net in var.Network : [
         for sn_key, sn in net.Subnets : [
           for vm_key, vm in var.VirtualMachine : {
             reg_key  = reg_key
             lz_key   = lz_key
             net_key  = net_key
             sn_key   = sn_key
             vm_key   = vm_key
             vm_size  = vm.Size
             vm_os    = vm.Disks.OS
             vm_image = vm.Image
           }
         ] if sn_key == "Access"
       ]
     ]
   ]
 ]) : "${v.reg_key}.${v.sn_key}" => v
 if v.reg_key == "Primary" && v.lz_key == "Primary" && v.net_key == "Primary" || v.reg_key == "Secondary" && v.lz_key == "Secondary" && v.net_key == "Secondary"
```

}

Below are the provided, (Primary 2VMs and Secondary 2VMs)

```
VirtualMachine = {
 Primary = {
runtime-1 = {
  Size = "Standard_B2ms"

  Disks = {
    OS = {
      Cache = "ReadWrite"
      Size  = 128
      Type  = "Standard_LRS"
    }
    Data = {}
  }
  Image = {
    Publisher = "MicrosoftWindowsServer"
    Offer     = "WindowsServer"
    Sku       = "2022-datacenter-azure-edition-core"
    Version   = "latest"
  }
}
runtime-2 = {
  Size = "Standard_B2ms"

  Disks = {
    OS = {
      Cache = "ReadWrite"
      Size  = 128
      Type  = "Standard_LRS"
    }
    Data = {}
  }
  Image = {
    Publisher = "MicrosoftWindowsServer"
    Offer     = "WindowsServer"
    Sku       = "2022-datacenter-azure-edition-core"
    Version   = "latest"
  }
}
```

}

```
Secondary = {
runtime-1 = {
  Size = "Standard_B2ms"

  Disks = {
    OS = {
      Cache = "ReadWrite"
      Size  = 128
      Type  = "Standard_LRS"
    }
    Data = {}
  }
  Image = {
    Publisher = "MicrosoftWindowsServer"
    Offer     = "WindowsServer"
    Sku       = "2022-datacenter-azure-edition-core"
    Version   = "latest"
  }
}
runtime-2 = {
  Size = "Standard_B2ms"

  Disks = {
    OS = {
      Cache = "ReadWrite"
      Size  = 128
      Type  = "Standard_LRS"
    }
    Data = {}
  }
  Image = {
    Publisher = "MicrosoftWindowsServer"
    Offer     = "WindowsServer"
    Sku       = "2022-datacenter-azure-edition-core"
    Version   = "latest"
  }
}
```

}
}

please suggest if I need to make any further changes?

I have even tried using vars instead locals and feels inexperienced while handling vm extensions

Comment: Please update the code in text format as it is difficult to get the code info from the image. Thanks.

Comment: Apologies, updated the codespace

Comment: have you made any progress so far? @Mahs

Comment: Sorry Vinay, have not been here around on this topic. The method which you've suggested would leave me to expose the vars under locals. Instead, wanted to call out the declared vars using flatten loop method. Any recommendations would you suggest?

Answer (score 0):

> I tried to use a flattened loop for reading multiple VM regions I was able to make the necessary changes in the module mentioned and tried to rewrite the configuration again.

The code you've provided appears to be a Terraform expression using the `flatten` function to generate a map based on some input conditions. I'll walk you through creating a Terraform configuration using the Azure provider and your provided information.

- It focuses on creating a' advmAccess' map based on nested iterations over different variables and local values.
- It uses a complex `flatten` expression combined with nested `for` loops to iterate over multiple structures and filter out the required elements.
- It doesn’t define any resource or provider; it’s purely handling data within Terraform

You've provided configurations for two virtual machines for both primary and secondary regions.

Instead, I tried the following requirements for the better achievement of your requirements.

**My Terraform configuration module:**

```
locals {
  regions = {
    Primary   = {},
    Secondary = {}
  }

  landingZone = {
    Primary   = {},
    Secondary = {}
  }

  Network = {
    Primary = {
      Subnets = {
        Access = {}
      }
    },
    Secondary = {
      Subnets = {
        Access = {}
      }
    }
  }

  VirtualMachine = {
    Primary = {
      runtime-1 = {
        Size = "Standard_B2ms"
        Disks = {
          OS = {
            Cache = "ReadWrite"
            Size  = 128
            Type  = "Standard_LRS"
          }
          Data = {}
        }
        Image = {
          Publisher = "MicrosoftWindowsServer"
          Offer     = "WindowsServer"
          Sku       = "2022-datacenter-azure-edition-core"
          Version   = "latest"
        }
      },
      runtime-2 = {
        Size = "Standard_B2ms"
        Disks = {
          OS = {
            Cache = "ReadWrite"
            Size  = 128
            Type  = "Standard_LRS"
          }
          Data = {}
        }
        Image = {
          Publisher = "MicrosoftWindowsServer"
          Offer     = "WindowsServer"
          Sku       = "2022-datacenter-azure-edition-core"
          Version   = "latest"
        }
      }
    },
    Secondary = {
      runtime-1 = {
        Size = "Standard_B2ms"
        Disks = {
          OS = {
            Cache = "ReadWrite"
            Size  = 128
            Type  = "Standard_LRS"
          }
          Data = {}
        }
        Image = {
          Publisher = "MicrosoftWindowsServer"
          Offer     = "WindowsServer"
          Sku       = "2022-datacenter-azure-edition-core"
          Version   = "latest"
        }
      },
      runtime-2 = {
        Size = "Standard_B2ms"
        Disks = {
          OS = {
            Cache = "ReadWrite"
            Size  = 128
            Type  = "Standard_LRS"
          }
          Data = {}
        }
        Image = {
          Publisher = "MicrosoftWindowsServer"
          Offer     = "WindowsServer"
          Sku       = "2022-datacenter-azure-edition-core"
          Version   = "latest"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_machine" "vm" {
  for_each = local.VirtualMachine

  name                  = each.key
  location              = "East US" # Update with your preferred region
  vm_size               = each.value.Size
  resource_group_name   = "your-resource-group" # Update this

  storage_os_disk {
    name          = "osdisk"
    caching       = each.value.Disks.OS.Cache
    create_option = "FromImage"
    managed_disk_type = each.value.Disks.OS.Type
  }

  storage_image_reference {
    publisher = each.value.Image.Publisher
    offer     = each.value.Image.Offer
    sku       = each.value.Image.Sku
    version   = each.value.Image.Version
  }

  os_profile {
    computer_name  = each.key
    admin_username = "adminuser" # Update as needed
    admin_password = "Password1234!" # Update as needed
  }

  os_profile_windows_config {}

  network_interface_ids = ["your-network-interface-id"] # Update this

  tags = {
    environment = "testing"
  }
}
```

This solution will help you with the drawbacks of the configuration mentioned in the query

- It is a more comprehensive code, aiming to create actual Azure Virtual Machine resources based on the local `VirtualMachine` variable.
- It defines the `azurerm` provider, and the `azurerm_virtual_machine` resource, which are essential parts of a functional Terraform configuration to create resources in Azure.
- It provides actual resource definitions and configurations, which, when applied, would create resources in your Azure subscription.